# Problems with reading text from a file

Tags: c++, getline

I have this function that reads the text from a file and adds it to a string, now the weird thing is that it works fine if its a short text. But if its a longer text the string becomes empty, any help solving this problem is appreciated.

```
 string inlasning(string namn)
{
    string filString, temp;

    ifstream filen(namn.c_str());

    if(!filen.good())
    {
        cout << "Otillganglig fil" << endl;
        filString = "ERROR";
        return filString;
    }
    else
    {
        while(!filen.eof())
            getline(filen, temp);
            filString.append(temp);
    }

    filen.close();
    return filString;

}
```

Comment: check that your data doesn't have new lines dispersed in the middle of strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Don't use `eof()` to control the loop. Put `getline` directly into the loop condition. Search StackOverflow if you have problems doing this.

2) Your while loop has no braces and thus only covers the `getline` line, despite your misleading indentation.

3) `getline` discards newlines. Your final string will be wrong.

4) The actual behavior you're observing comes from the fact that you only append the very last thing that `getline` returns to your string. When your file contains one line of text and doesn't end in a newline, this will seem to work. If it has more lines but doesn't end in a newline, you'll only get the last line. If the file does end in a newline, because of your incorrect loop condition the last call to `getline` will actually give you an empty string, which will be exactly the contents of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while(!filen.eof())
    getline(filen, temp);
    filString.append(temp);
```

with

```
while(!filen.eof())
{
    getline(filen, temp);
    filString.append(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "is_open()" to check if the file exists:

`if( ! filen.is_open() ){...}` // you don't need an else clause

...And your while loop must has braces or it will only execute the getline(...) instruction:

```
while( filen.good() ) {
    getline( filen , temp );
    filString += ( temp + '\n' );
}
```

If your file doesn't ends with '\n', remove the last char from the string